# SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5

I am deploying myapp.war with unpackwars=false in tomcat 5.5.

I am getting this error

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive myapp.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/myapp]).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jul 22, 2014 6:01:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 22, 2014 6:01:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

But it is working with `unpackwars=true`. Is anything I am doing wrong?

How can I fix it?